# Cobertura Report Generation Issue

Tags: html, xml, maven, cobertura

I am facing an issue in generating cobertura report. Files getting compiles successfully. but during report generation i am getting import error as package not found.

Comment: Please fine attached log   [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 107 source files to D:\TCare\Tcare Workspace\tcare_latest\tcare-ejb\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] D:\TCare\Tcare Workspace\tcare_latest\tcare-ejb\src\test\java\com\tcs\telecom\tib\tcare\services\TestPpmServicesImpl.java:[11,17] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR

Comment: You should edit your question for providing more information instead of add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation of your tests fails.
You need to add TestNG's jar to your classpath when executing your command.

By the way, you should precise how you launch your command.
And you should use a build system (Maven for example) which could help you manage your dependencies.